# Mouse Interactions on visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms

I am Making an auto clicker for a friend i was just wondering how to make the program do the auto clicking (left and right click) i'm using windows form app .net framework

Comment: You could probably just make a Visual Studio extension rather than automating the UI with a program.

Comment: If you didn't want to proceed with John's fine comment and are keen on clicking, then I suggest _Windows UI Automation_

Comment: Where do you want to `do the auto clikcing`? Inside the form? Or elsewhere on the screen?

Comment: @KyleWang  for a button in the GUI, its a test button

Comment: @KyleWang do you have discord or other means of which can communicate

Comment: @kactus Sorry, can't do that. Let's communicate here. You want to click a button via code? To achieve "left click", you can use `Button.PerformClick`. Or you can refer to the article [Auto Clicker C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32556/Auto-Clicker-C). It can simulate mouse click correctly

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, the simplest way is to:

1. Add a button and set it's Visible property to false.
2. Create a timer and set it's desired interval.
3. In the tick event of the timer, you can add the following code:

   `yourButtonNameHere.PerformClick();` or `yourButtonNameHere_Click(sender, e);`
4. If you want to keep the timer running always, set it's Enabled property to true in the Designer itself. Else, use `yourTimerNameHere.Start();` whenever you want to start the timer and `youTimerNameHere.Stop();` whenever you want to stop it.
5. **The Last Step:** If you don't want to use the timer or have some other requirement, let me know!

> Make sure to add some work to the Click event of the button else nothing happens!

**EDIT:**
If you want to simulate a right-click on a button that is in your GUI, it is even simple.

You don't need to have a separate event for a right-click.

You can pass a variable whenever you want to simulate the click for e.g. an int of 1 for left click and int 0 for right-click.

Then in the click event of the button, add a check that if int is 1 then do some left click work and if int is 0 then do some right-click work.

Comment: @kactus: I just thought that using a timer was the only way to click an invisible button. If you need it without a timer, pls let me know.

Comment: @D J this will make the mouse click on its own, is this for left click or right click, also would there be a way to send you my code 
because i don't want the button to be clicking without mouse input i just want the mouse to continuously right click. i already have the code to make it left click

Comment: @kactus: Please read the **EDIT:** section of my answer.